# PHP changing number in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, int

I have this PHP code:

```
if ($username) {
    if ($news == 1)
        $int = "9";
    if ($news == 0)
        $int = "12";
}
else
    $int = "9";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE active='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $int");
require ("scripts/connect.php");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

But then I get this error (Note the line starting with $numrows is line 69):

> > Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Site/index.php on line 69

I have tried many ways of changing the number to no avail.  Please help!  Thanks!

Comment: would you be so polite to check `mysql_error()` ??

Comment: And proppably there is an error because you connect using `require ("scripts/connect.php");` before query

Comment: Better also to use mysqli or PDO, as mysql is no longer supported.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski $news is always set to 1 or 0 in my database

Comment: Just FYI - -1 from me for using StackOverflow where you could just debug your code by yourself

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Have some mercy, Peter. I've seen much worse posts here (which I then -1 as well), but he may just be very newbie. Guide him politely and we all would benefit from this in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `scripts/connect.php` is responsible for establishing database connection, then I belive `mysql_query()` should be **below** it, not **above** as it is now. I also recommend using `mysql_error()` and always check return values for errors, as assumptions like "query is always successful" are no-no approach and will hit you badly in less expected moment.

```
require ("scripts/connect.php");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE active='1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $int");
if( $query ) {
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
  ...
} else {
   die( mysql_error() );
}
```

Please note `mysql` extension is deprecated. Switch to `mysqli` or something more sophisticated like `PDO` as soon as you can.

Comment: @user22138 Glad to hear so. Accept the answer then :)

Comment: Couldn't when I commented (10 mins)